# Performance difference between poll and consumer in kafka

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka

I am looking to use the confluent-kafka-python API to consume messages from a single kafka topic, is there any difference in performance between kafka [consume](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.DeserializingConsumer.consume)() and the [poll](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.DeserializingConsumer.poll)() for accumulating small(eg 10) or large (eg 1000-10000) messages as batches? poll() returns only one message at a time, so we need a custom logic to handle the batching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DeserializingConsumer` (the class you linked to docs for) dose not support `consume()`, it only provides the `poll()` method. If this is the class you plan to use, `poll()` is your only option.

The regular `confluent_kafka.Consumer` class does support both, though. If you use the regular `Consumer` and your intention is to process batches of messages, I recommend using `consume()` to avoid the complexity required to achieve similar semantics with `poll()`. As for a performance difference, both are quite efficient and designed to be called in the critical path. The primary difference to consider is the semantics.

Since `poll()` triggers callbacks, calling `poll()` can trigger a rebalance callback before the application has accumulated the desired number of messages in a batch, at which point the consumer probably has to decide what to do with those messages. In a stop-the-world rebalance, all partitions are revoked from the consumer, which is simple and can make cleanup straight forward. In an incremental rebalance, some, but not all partitions may be lost during the rebalance, so make sure this is handled correctly.

`consume()` also triggers callbacks, but handling rebalances is much simpler because there is no partially accumulated batch of messages stored between calls.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the regular `Consumer` can be used only for json schemas, while the `DeserializingConsumer` is used for avro and protobuf schemas?